# how to allow multiselect to a dropdown generated from a view generated by entity framework in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have Generated views, controller using entity framework for a table resourceaccessProfile.
I have a dropdown for Resource which is a foreign key relationship with another table called resources. The view which is generated shows a dropdown to display all the resources. 
Now i want this to allow choosing multiple resources.

The problem i am having is how to store the multiple selected resources in the database and how to allow to choose multiple from the dropdown?

From what i have seen from other SO posts i need to use a view model, but i am not sure how i would need to implement it.

Pls be gentle, i am pretty much a novice with mvc, try to get to understand the basics of it

Model:

```
 public partial class ResourceAccessProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Profile { get; set; }
    public int Resource { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> isActive { get; set; }

    public virtual Profile Profile1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Resource Resource1 { get; set; }
}

 public partial class Resource
{
    public Resource()
    {
        this.ResourceAccesses = new HashSet<ResourceAccess>();
        this.Links = new HashSet<Link>();
        this.ResourceAccessProfiles = new HashSet<ResourceAccessProfile>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int ResourceType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ResourceMenuOrder { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Open_New_Window { get; set; }

    public virtual ResourceType ResourceType1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ResourceAccess> ResourceAccesses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ResourceAccessProfile> ResourceAccessProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Id,Profile,Resource,isActive")] ResourceAccessProfile resourceaccessprofile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ResourceAccessProfiles.Add(resourceaccessprofile);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.Profile = new SelectList(db.Profiles, "Id", "name", resourceaccessprofile.Profile);
        ViewBag.Resource = new SelectList(db.Resources, "Id", "Name", resourceaccessprofile.Resource);
        return View(resourceaccessprofile);
    }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ResourceAccessProfile</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Profile, "Profile", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Profile", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Profile)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Resource, "Resource", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Resource", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Resource)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.isActive, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.isActive)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.isActive)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use view-model then you can use hidden field for Profile. After change event of drop-down you can keep its values by (comma separated) to 'Profile' Hidden field.

and for multiselecting drop-down you should add attribute 'multiple' to dropdown like,

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProfileList", String.Empty, new { @multiple = "true"})
```

Comment: Its not that i dont want to use view model, its just that i am not sure how to do that. Any pointers would be helpful